# Buy and sell stock in a day

Tags: algorithm

I was asked this problem in a interview:

[Best Time to Buy and Sell Stock](http://www.leetcode.com/2010/11/best-time-to-buy-and-sell-stock.html)

Say you have an array for which the ith element is the price of a given stock on day i.
If you were only permitted to buy one share of the stock and sell one share of the stock, design an algorithm to find the best times to buy and sell. I was able to give an O(n) algorithm.

While the interviewer asked me a followed on question, what is the case with "buy one, sell one", and then "buy one, sell one", which means there are two trades in one day, maximize the profit. I was able to give an O(n^2) algorithm. But the interviewer said it can be improved. Is there a O(n) algorithm?

The interviewer said that you can not buy two share at the same time. You must buy one sell it, and then buy one at another time, then sell it.

Comment: Wait, so you were able to give O(n) algorithm, but now you're asking whether it exists? I don't get it. Also, the site you linked to seems to contain the answer you're looking for.

Comment: @svick - Fan appears to be saying he solved the single "buy one then sell one" problem in O(n) and was then asked for the "buy one then sell one then buy one then sell one" problem; it is the second problem for which he wants to know if there's an O(n) solution.

Comment: How exactly does it work? Can you “buy one, buy another one, sell one, sell the other one”? And can you buy or sell two shares at the same moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The O(n) solution given in the original question's [reference](http://www.leetcode.com/2010/11/best-time-to-buy-and-sell-stock.html) gives the optimal "buy one then sell one" answer for each prefix of the original array.  That algorithm could also be trivially modified to cope with the "backwards" situation; i.e. a "sell one then buy one" where you are working backwards from the array; that's equivalent to having the "buy one then sell one" answer for each suffix of the array.

Now, in the "buy, sell, buy, sell" case we have some point (after the first sell) where we are somewhere within our array, say *b*.  For that breakpoint the best solution would be the best prefix solution for *0..b* and the best suffix solution for *b+1..n*.  The best "buy, sell, buy, sell" overall is the optimum of these optimum solutions.

So, to solve the "buy, sell, buy, sell" in *O(n)*, you can solve the prefix in *O(n)*, suffix in *O(n)*, and then for each breakpoint calculate the optimum - so *nO(1)*.  That's an *O(n)* algorithm using *O(n)* space.

Answer (score 0):

It could be optimized to have only one for loop, but the idea is basically the same:

```
int maxProfit(vector<int> &prices) {        
    if (prices.empty()) return 0;        

    int n = prices.size();
    int lHolding = prices[0], rHolding = prices[n-1];
    int lMax = 0, rMax = 0;        

    vector<int> profit(n);

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {            
        if (prices[i] > lHolding) {
            lMax = max(lMax, prices[i] - lHolding);
        } else {
            lHolding = prices[i];
        }

        profit[i] += lMax;

        int right = n - 1 - i;

        if (rHolding > prices[right]) {
            rMax = max(rMax, rHolding - prices[right]);
        } else {
            rHolding = prices[right];
        }

        profit[right] += rMax;            
    }

    return *max_element(profit.begin(), profit.end());        
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please remove this answer and _edit_ your previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am late to the game, but here it is.  First, the solution given by borrible isn't quite clear in that it is possible for someone to implement that and get O(n^2).  This is simply by looping through b, for each b, compute prefix and suffix, which are O(n) each, so together it is O(n)*(n) where (n) is from b=1...n.  This means that the outcome is O(n^2).

To implement that description so that it runs in O(n), one would need to recognize that prefix and postfix are independent and can be run separately as implemented by Daniel.

The problem with this solution is that it requires a O(n) space.  Suppose your stock trace were 1 giga points (which is quite common if you were to, for example, iterate through 2 years worth of data), then you would blow up memory usage.

If I were the interviewer, the next logical question is: is it possible to remove the memory requirement?

Let me give that a shot.  Most of it is just working out basic math.

we have an array prices[0...n-1].

In the original problem, we would like to find r,s where 0<=r<s<n such that

p = prices[s] - prices[r]

is maximized.

In the new problem, we would like to find i,j,k,l where 0<=i<j<k<l<n such that

q = prices[j]-prices[i]+prices[l]-prices[k]

is maximized.

(supposing n>=4, i.e. no degenerate case, which we can easily handle)

Suppose we solved the original problem, then the solution to the new problem can be divided into 3 cases:

1. i=r<j=s<k<l
2. i<j<k=r<l=s
3. i=r<j<k<l=s

It's actually easy to prove this by reductio ad absurdum (i.e. suppose not, then perturb either i or k to r and either j or l to s.  this perturbation would increase q, contradicting the original supposition).

Ok, the solution then is simple:

a.  find r,s in O(n)
b.  check case 1 in O(n) 
c.  check case 2 in O(n)
d.  check case 3 in O(n)
e.  return max of b,c,d.

in fact, b, c, and d can be executed in n iterations.  In total is 2 O(n) + O(1) which is O(n).  There is also a fixed number of variables that get juggled around, so the space requirement is O(1).

```
int maxProfit(vector<int> &prices) {        
    int n = prices.size();

    int b, a;
    int m1 = 0;
    int hb;

    b = a = 0;
    hb = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (prices[i] < prices[hb]) {
            hb = i;
        }
        if (prices[i] - prices[hb] > m1) {
            m1 = prices[i] - prices[hb];
            b = hb; a = i;
        }
    }

    int before = 0, after = 0;
    if (b > 0) {
        int bb, ba;
        before = 0;
        int bhb;

        bb = ba = 0;
        bhb = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < b-1; i++) {
            if (prices[i] < prices[bhb]) {
                bhb = i;
            } 
            if (prices[i] - prices[bhb] > before) {
                before = prices[i] - prices[bhb];
                bb = bhb; ba = i;
            }
        }
    }
    if (a < n) {
        int ab, aa;
        int ahb;

        ab = aa = a+1;
        ahb = a+1;
        after = 0;
        for (int i = a+2; i < n; i++) {
            if (prices[i] < prices[ahb]) {
                ahb = i;
            } 
            if (prices[i] - prices[ahb] > after) {
                after = prices[i] - prices[ahb];
                ab = ahb; aa = i;
            }
        }

    }


    int hmb = before + m1;
    int hma = after + m1;
    int hm = max(hmb,hma);

    int tm = b;
    for (int j = b+1; j < a; j++) {
        if (prices[j] > prices[tm]) {
            tm = j;
        }
        m1 = prices[tm] - prices[b] + prices[a] - prices[j];
        hm = max(hm,m1);
    }

    return hm;
}
```

There may be some degenerate cases that I forgot, but it's been taking me longer to write this reply than coming up with the simple solution, so if there's a bug, you're on your own.  The math seems to work out though, so it's probably right.